# How to connect SQL Server in Rails and Microsoft ODBC driver for linux?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-server, linux, activerecord

I'm deploying my rails app on a remote machine. On my local machine, I use activerecord-sqlserver-adapter which depends on tiny_tds and freetds to talk to SQL Server. It's very easy to configure and use. However on the remote one, it doesn't have freetds, but only contains Microsoft® SQL Server® ODBC Driver 1.0 for Linux (http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=28160). Because tiny_tds needs freetds, I can no longer use tiny_tds for activerecord-sqlserver-adapter. Now I get stuck and don't know how and where to start.

Please help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Why not install freetds on the machine? They have packages in official repos of all major distros

Comment: How I want I can install freetds on that machine... The remote one is an app engine so I can't install freetds on it.